# identity which include continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

In this encyclopedia, 
http://encyclopedia-of-equation.webnode.jp/including-continued-fraction/

I found this identity.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} \frac{2n}{(n^2+r^2)^2}+  \frac{1}{ (k-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1+4r^2}{4} + \frac{\frac{1^4(1^2+4r^2)}{4(2\cdot1-1)(2\cdot1+1)}}{ (k-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}(2\cdot1^2+2\cdot1+1+4r^2) - \frac{\frac{2^4(2^2+4r^2)}{4(2\cdot2-1)(2\cdot2+1)}}{(k-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}(2\cdot2^2+2\cdot2+1+4r^2) - \frac{\frac{3^4(3^2+4r^2)}{4(2\cdot3-1)(2\cdot3+1)}}{
                     (k-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{1}{4}(2\cdot3^2+2\cdot3+1+4r^2) - \cdots}}}}
=\frac{1}{r}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x-1}\sin{(rx)}dx~~~~~~~~~~x>\frac{1}{2}~~~~~r>0$$

I tried to understand why the right side does not include $k$.

Can anybody explain why?

Comment: The big formula appears very badly in my device. It exceeds the edge of the page! Can somebody help fixing it?

Comment: The right hand side includes a condition on a dummy variable. Is this a typesetting exercise instead of a correct equation?